# Difference between running code in shell and from file

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to the csv module (and Python in general). I was running some test code to write a CSV file and I realized that it functions when I run it in the shell but not when I run it from a file in IDLE. When I try the latter, it tells me that "open" is invalid syntax. What's going on here?

```
import csv
with open('csvtest.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
```

Comment: What version(s) of python (from shell and from within IDLE)?

Comment: are you using both of the same versions of Python? I.e., in the shell as well as the IDE? What version(s)?

Comment: Your IDLE most likely is running on an older version of Python.

Comment: IIRC, the `open` function was added long, long ago, like 2.0 or 2.2 or so. But the `with` statement was added in 2.6, so it's very likely that you're using, e.g., Python 2.5, and the `with` is the actual `SyntaxError`. (If you pasted the complete output, we could see where the caret is and not have to guess…) If you want to test this, try writing `f = open('csvtest.csv')` and see if that's invalid syntax too—if not, then it's the `with`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

> *New in version 2.5.*
>
> The with statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with
>   methods defined by a context manager (see section With Statement
>   Context Managers).

Your IDLE is probably running Python 2.4 or earlier.

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks. I'm wondering, though, why when I remove the with statement:

   `import csv
    f = open('csvtest.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'))`

it runs, but doesn't write the CSV file. Is the with statement necessary to make the write object work?